# Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in .... papaparse

Tags: npm, papaparse, npm-audit

Im getting this error using ngx-papaparse in angular. It was working, I then tried adding jquery to my project, and in the process was warned of security issues, so I followed instructions and tried npm audit fix.  In the process something seems to have gone awry and now I'm getting...

> ERROR in ./node_modules/papaparse/papaparse.min.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
>   '/mnt/c/Users/j2wil/Documents/CodingDojo/projects/Scouts/public/node_modules/papaparse

I've tried a number of things including removing node_modules and npm install. Also deleting packages.json and reinstalling.  But I keep seeing the same error.

Comment: seems to be related to https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/issues/517

Answer (score 9):

I had the similar issue. Please try installing the stream package.

```
npm install stream --save
```